# How Does Variance Propagate From Likelihood Function To MCMC Posterior?

Tags: bayesian, variance, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, likelihood

Suppose we are trying to obtain the posterior distribution of three parameters that influence a discretely observed population. The likelihood function is unfortunately intractable, as it is a mix of birth, sudden expansion, death, and sampling.

Instead say, for each parameter input, we simulate the process a hundred thousand times for our species, and determine a likelihood based on the joint distribution of 2-3 population outcomes (e.g. change in diversity, total population size, etc).  But the simulation is computationally taxing, and furthermore, kernel estimation of the joint probability density of the outcomes takes time. To get a highly precise likelihood, given all this, it takes ~30 seconds, on a supercomputer.

Thus, accuracy is necessarily a tradeoff between chain iterations in MCMC (Metropolis-Hastings) and the variance of the likelihood function.  My question is, (1) is there a known way to deal with situations like this, and (2) how will variance in the likelihood function impact the posterior distribution.

Thanks!

Comment: I learned about Approximate Bayesian Computation, which for this practical problem seems to provide a solution.  However, in general, I remain curious about the central question - how will unbiased variance in likelihood estimation impact the posterior.

Comment: Did you make any progress regarding question (2)?